# Basic information about text editors and html output

Tags: html, rich-text-editor

I'm a brand-newbie to coding. I am looking for a text editor that displays HTML output (hopefully with troubleshooting error messages, like with compiled languages). Does that exist? Does Notepad ++ have this capability?

Also, if my question indicates that I am misunderstanding some basic significant aspect of the front-end design process, I am all ears. Please assume I know absolutely nothing about web development because I know absolutely nothing about web development. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are looking for is html linting and/or synthaxical check. Some code editors offer it as a plugin, some IDEs have it built-in. You should orientate your researches towards that. Cheers

Comment: The best way to learn HTML for me back in the days was to hit F5 like a freak each time I changed somthing in the source file ;)

Answer (score 0):

Note that text editors are not for displaying html output... The browser displays your html out.